# Add responsive text to the center of a Donut chart

Tags: angular, ng2-charts, donut-chart

I have a Donut chart I would like to add the text "6" and "Total" to the center and the text should be responsive, i.e. if I resize the chart the text has to resize along with it. I have done the following:

**TS**

```
refreshChart(){
  let comp_tot=this.total_count;
  
  // console.log(this.total_count);
  let d = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('totalChart');
  //  (<HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById('appraised_count_comp')).innerText = comp_appraised;
  // (<HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById('pending_count_comp')).innerText = comp_pending;
  var data = {
    labels: [
      
      "Done",
      "Not Done",
      "Pending"
    ],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [this.done_count, this.not_done_count,this.pending_count],
        backgroundColor: [
          "#198754",
          "#dc3545",
          "#ffc107"
        ],
        cutoutPercentage : 5,
      }]
  };

  var promisedDeliveryChart = new Chart(d, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: data,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
     
      legend: {
        display: true,
        align: 'end'
      },
      cutoutPercentage : 50,
    }
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
  Chart.pluginService.register({
    beforeDraw: function (chart: any) {
        console.log(chart)
      var width = chart.chart.width,
        height = chart.chart.height,
        ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
      ctx.restore();
      if((<HTMLInputElement>(document.getElementById("perc_comp"))) != null){
        (<HTMLInputElement>(document.getElementById("perc_comp"))).innerText = comp_tot.toString()
      }
      let txt1="Total";
      let txt2=comp_tot;

      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    
      const centerX = ((chart.chartArea.left + chart.chartArea.right) / 2);
      const centerY = ((chart.chartArea.top + chart.chartArea.bottom) / 2);

      //Get the width of the string and also the width of the element minus 10 to give it 5px side padding
      const sidePadding = 60;
      const sidePaddingCalculated = (sidePadding / 100) * (chart.innerRadius * 2)

      const stringWidth = ctx.measureText(txt1).width;
      const elementWidth = (chart.innerRadius * 2) - sidePaddingCalculated;

      // Find out how much the font can grow in width.
      const widthRatio = elementWidth / stringWidth;
      const newFontSize = Math.floor(30 * widthRatio);
      const elementHeight = (chart.innerRadius * 2);

      // Pick a new font size so it will not be larger than the height of label.
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
      //var fontSizeToUse = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
      const fontSizeToUse = 5;
      ctx.font = fontSizeToUse + 'em Montserrat, sans-serif';
      ctx.fillStyle = 'black';

      // Draw text in center
      ctx.fillText(txt2, centerX, centerY - 10);
      var fontSizeToUse1 = 1.5;
      ctx.font = fontSizeToUse1 + 'em Montserrat, sans-serif';
      ctx.fillText(txt1, centerX, centerY + 30);

      ctx.save();
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

At present the text does not resize. Is there a way to make the text responsive also the text doesn't exactly look centered, is there a mistake in my calculation?

Comment: are you using what chart library with angular for donut-chart ?

Comment: I am using :import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';